# Dynamic rendering of D3 charts - D3.js selectAll function is not working when Lightning Locker is enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, locker-service

In our application, we are using D3.js to dynamically altering SVG components using the code as below.

```
    linkContainer.selectAll("line").remove();        
    var link = self.drawLinks(linkContainer, links);        
    self.context.nodeContainer.selectAll("g").remove();
```

Here, once we enable locker service, i think we can't grab line tags and thus selectAll function in not valid anymore. We are facing below error.

```
   Error in $A.getCallback() [linkContainer.selectAll is not a function]
```

Thanks for helping on this one.

Comment: D3 wasn't working several months ago - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143697/list-of-things-that-do-and-do-not-work-with-locker-service.

Comment: It seems, we have to modify d3.Js file or move our implemention on new version I.e. Ver 4.x.

Comment: If you have a good list of which versions of which libraries work with locker service, please post as an answer and it'll get my +1.

Comment: @ThisIsRSN Is this working as expected after upgrading D3 versions?

Comment: @ThisIsRSN If this is not working after upgrading to version 4.x of D3, can you provide your markup and enough info to reproduce the issue locally so we can investigate.