# Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined, while LockerService (LS) is active

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I am using `d3.js` in my lightning component, I am getting following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

This error occurs when I active my `LockerService (LS)`. Otherwise it works.

The problem is each user of my component have to `deactive` `LockerService (LS)`.

Comment: FYI [Dynamic rendering of D3 charts - D3.js selectAll function is not working when Lighting Locker is enabled](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158293/dynamic-rendering-of-d3-charts-d3-js-selectall-function-is-not-working-when-li) though there is no clear comment or answer there.

Comment: See [Which external JS libs work with Lightning Locker Service?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html). You may be able to fix by moving to a different version of D3.

Comment: according to Salesforce doc it is supported - check to see if your version is the one that is supported in [Keith C](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) shared url - v 4.4.0